# Android Room Database Creation - Callback

Tags: android, android-room

I am using Android Room in my project and I came across the following question:

- Is Room's database creation callback ([`RoomDatabase.Callback#onCreate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Callback.html#onCreate(android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase))) guaranteed to **always be called**? If so, is it safe to run insert queries in this callback to prepopulate the database - queries which if not executed, will make the app crash everytime the user opens it?

The reason I am asking this is because, currently, I am doing exactly that on my app. I am taking advantage of that callback to prepopulate my database, but I am seeing crashes occurring with some users, repeatedly. Thoses crashes occur when the app tries to get one of these prepopulated data, but they do not exist (0 rows are returned).

---

```
fun getInstance(context: Context): MyDatabaseClass {
    if (isDeletingDatabase) throw DeletingDatabaseException()
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = Room
                .databaseBuilder(context, MyDatabaseClass::class.java, MyDatabaseClass.DB_NAME)
                .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                        onDbCreated(db)
                    }
                })
                .addMigrations(
                        Migration_1_2,
                        Migration_2_3
                )
                .build()
    }
    return instance!!
}
```

Comment: Hi, here is a small example, maybe with this you can change your database.
https://github.com/jsperk/PocRoom
regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Room's database creation callback (RoomDatabase.Callback#onCreate)
>   guaranteed to always be called?

As per the documentation, it is called when the database is created for the first time, after all tables are created.

One case in which `onCreate()` is not called (although you might expect it to be) is when a migration to the current version is not found and `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` is set on the db builder. In this case the db gets recreated without calling `onCreate()`. Whether this is by design, I am not sure, but it is currently the case.

> If so, is it safe to run insert queries in this callback to
>   prepopulate the database - queries which if not executed, will make
>   the app crash everytime the user opens it?

It is safe to populate the database here, assuming that it is called when you expect it to be, which from my understanding is only when the database is created the first time.

So, if Room can't find migration items for certain versions, there could be crashes if your app is not designed to handle missing data.

---

**My observations about how Room handles migrations (as of [v2.2.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.2.0-alpha01)):**

According to the documentation for `addMigrations()`:

> If a migration item is missing between current version and the latest
>   version, Room will clear the database and recreate..

This may be the case, but it also throws the following IllegalStateException:

> A migration from 1 to 2 was required but not found. Please provide the
>   necessary Migration path via
>   RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...) or allow for
>   destructive migrations via one of the
>   RoomDatabase.Builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration* methods.

If you add `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` to your database builder, as the exception suggests, the database does get recreated (or at least wiped), but `onCreate()` is not called, so if your population code is in there, you will end up with no data for your app.

For this reason, I believe `onCreate()` is a viable option to populate your database as long as you promise to provide Room with all the necessary migrations it might need.